# Write a letter in InputField at Caret Position

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, button, text, onclick

I have created some buttons in Unity. When a button is clicked a function is called to write text on an `InputText` component. The function is following for example:

```
public void JButton()
{
    textshowed.text = textshowed.text + "J";
}
```

But if I want to write a letter in between a line, the word is written at last of line.
What should i do for the letter to written where the cursor/caret is?

Comment: try to use Input Fields: https://docs.unity3d.com/es/2018.4/Manual/script-InputField.html

Comment: i am using input field..But writting text in it on button press

Comment: Now I get your problem, and I'm sorry but Unity have no methods or variables exposed to show the location of the caret, so you have to code your own InputField to achieve that

Comment: I hope you don't have a component for each and every letter of the alphabet .... rather use always the component and use a `public void Button(string value) { textshowed.text += value; }` and configure the according `string` value via the Inspector ...

Comment: @aqeel, have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that it doesnt handle selections in InputField. Below might be enough for your purpose?

```
public class button : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField myInput;
    int caretposition;
    public void JButton()
    {
        myInput.text = myInput.text.Insert(caretposition, "J");
        //Debug.Log(myInput.caretPosition);

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (myInput.isFocused)
        {
            caretposition = myInput.caretPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The button stopped working ..it is not writing anything

Comment: Ok changed the name onJClick() to JButton() to make it same as yours. Change it on your script too.

Comment: ok thanks alot! problem was of this  myInput.text = myInput.text.Insert(caretposition, "J");